# Is $P(X_t=Y_t,\forall\ 0\leq t < \infty )$ well defined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition

I have an elementary question about stochastic processes (continuous) and the notion of two processes being indistinguishable. Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}, Y=(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be two stochastic processes on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. I have the following definition, from *Karatzas, Shreve - Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

[image: 1]

Now there is this another definition, which comes from *Kannan, Lakshmikantham - Handbook of Stochastic Analysis with Aplications*.

[image: 2]

Basically it says that there is a measurable set $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $P(A)=1$ and $X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in A$ and all $0\leq t < \infty$. I've seen both definitions in different kind of formats, for example, this second definition is equivalent to this one, from *Achim Klenke- Probability Theory, A Comprehensive Course*.

[image: 3]

In this case, he is writing $\mathcal{A}$ instead $\mathcal{F}$.

The last two definition are well posed but the first one it's not, because   $$\{X_t=Y_t,\forall\ 0\leq t < \infty\} = \bigcap_{0\leq t < \infty}\{X_t=Y_t\}$$ 
is an uncountable intersections of measurable sets, and we know that this is not necessarily a measurable set. Therefore, if someone writes $P(X_t=Y_t, \forall\  0\leq t < \infty )$, then he/she is just **hoping** to have a $\sigma$-algebra rich enough to comport this set or he/she is just wrong (because they want to measure a non-measurable set).

On the other hand, the last two definition (in special, the definition from Kannan's) makes we think in a way that lead us to the first (and not necessarily well posed) definition. In fact, with that set $A\in\mathcal{F}$ defined above, we can kind of say $A = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega),\forall\ 0\leq t <\infty \}$, maybe not correct in some points of a null measure set. Now we can **kind of** write $P(A) = P(X_t=Y_t,\forall\ 0\leq t < \infty)$. Then we get the first definition, which would be correct, except, maybe, in a null measure set.

I have 2 interpretations of this situation, and I hope you can help me to have a correctly interpretation (maybe all my interpretations are wrong):

**1)** The first definition is in fact just a notation that we use when the conditions from the second definition are satisfied;

**2)** The first definition is not a notation, it means exactly this, but it's implied on the definition that the set $\{X_t=Y_t,\forall\ 0\leq t < \infty\}$ is measurable.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: In asserting "$\bigcap_{0\leq t < \infty}$" is  uncountable you are implicitly assuming the parameter space is uncountable.  Is that assumption actually made by the sources you are quoting?

Comment: @whuber Could you clarify? Because we have $t\in[0, \infty)$ and an intersection in this index set looks clearly not countable.

Comment: the parameter (index) space **is** uncountable, it's a continuous time parameter and it is explicitly said that $t$ is a real number varying continuously in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  (In many applications, $t$ is a natural number or integer.)  BTW, the Shreve and Karatzas definition (which I presume is the "first definition" that concerns you) is *identical* to the second one, because "$P[X_t=Y_t\ \forall t]$" is shorthand for $P\{\omega\,|\,X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)\ \forall t\}$, which can be read as the probability of the set of $\omega$ for which the two paths are the same.

Comment: I can't see how they are identical. In the first definition the measurable set is $\{\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)\ \forall t\}$, i.e., they explicitly gave you this set and say it is measurable with probability $1$. The second one says only that **exists** a measurable with probability $1$ and that in this set we have $X_t=Y_t$ for all $t$. And what bugs me more is that the set $\{\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)\ \forall t\}$ doesn't looks to necessarily be measurable because it's an uncountable intersection.

Comment: Isn't it usually assumed--or explicitly stated--that all measures have been *completed*? Thus, whether or not the sets in question are measurable shouldn't matter; all that matters is whether they (or their complements) are subsets of sets of measure zero. I believe this notion is implicit in the definition of "almost all."

Comment: "Achim - Probability Theory, A Comprehensive Course" >> Achim **Klenke** - Probability Theory, A Comprehensive Course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view of whuber's comments, I will post an answer. I think this settled the question and I don't feel this definition is strange anymore.

Saying that $X,Y$ will be indistinguishable if $P(X_t=Y_t,\forall\ 0\leq t < \infty) = 1$ was strange to me because we are asking for uncountable intersection to be measurable. So we may try weaken the definition saying that $X,Y$ will be indistinguishable if exists a measurable set $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $P(A) = 1$ and $X_t = Y_t$ in $A$ for all $0\leq t < \infty$.

It's true that $A\subset\{\omega\in\Omega: \ X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega), \forall\ 0\leq t < \infty \}$, but it may not be equal. Therefore there is a null set $N\subset\Omega$ such that $A\cup N = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega), \forall\ 0\leq t < \infty \}$.

As pointed out by whuber in the comentns, the probability space is supposed to be complete. So we have that $N$ is measurable, with $P(N) = 0$. In this case, we can just include $N$ in the definition and use $A\cup N$ instead of $A$. Therefore, the *weak* definition implies the *strong*, thus the definitions are equivalent.

**PS:** by a *null set* I mean a set contained in a measurable set with zero measure. Maybe the latter is called null set, I'm not sure. This is irrelevant when the space is complete, but I wanted to highlight the fact that this **is** relevant when the space is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

The "for all" suggests an intersection as opposed to a union.
$$
\{X_t = Y_t; \forall 0 \leq t < \infty\} = \bigcap_{t = 0}^{\infty} \{X_t = Y_t \}.
$$

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was a mistake. Still, this does not answer the question, for uncountable intersections are too not necessarily measurable.

Comment: Sigma algebras are closed under countable unions and intersections.

Comment: Yeah, countable, which is not the case here.

Comment: Ah, indeed.  Then I agree with you that definitions (2) and (3) are better defined.  That being said, if the processes are continuous then agreement on $\mathbb{Q}$ would mean agreement everywhere.

Comment: Intersection of disjoint sets?

Comment: Not necessarily disjoint.